# Using awk to pass specific string value of first column, if its not there then should pass 0 instead of NULL?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Below input file ABC.txt which we recieve have 2 columns seprated by "|" symbol

```
1st|2nd
AC|12
BV|24
BG|45
YT|67
```

using awk to check if AC exists in first column or not , if exists then pass it to to some variable

I made a code ,
It passes variable only if AC exists but pass null when there is no AC in ABC.txt. i am using this variable for some condition purpose. When it pass null value to variable then conditions fails.
I want to pass 0 when null come, and pass AC in variable ,even a single AC consist in first column of ABC.txt.

**I tried following**

```
variable = `awk -F\| '{ if($1 == "AC") print $1}' ABC.txt | sort -u`
```

**Expected output**

```
variable = 0 (when no AC consist in first column)
variable = AC (evan a single AC value consist in first column)
```

**Actual Output**

```
variable = NULL (when no AC consist in first column, 
                 so conditions fails when this variable 
                  used for conditional purpose)

variable = AC (evan a single AC value consist in first column)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=$(awk -F'|' '$1=="AC"{a=1}END{print a?"AC":"NULL"}' file)
```

Comment: let me try this, i will let you know

Comment: @user439643 if you want to have a `0` if there is no `AC`, you just change the `"NULL"` into `0`

Comment: why a =1 u hv taken, can you please explain ?

Comment: @user439643 `a=1`is used as a flag to see if there are any AC. If you like to get the number of `AC`, you can change Kents solution to: `var=$(awk -F'|' '$1=="AC"{a++}END{print a?a:"NULL"}' file)`

Comment: your solution is so perfect and compact that i still not able to understand/ i knw u used ternary operator...but how its working, m not able to get it

Comment: setting `a=1` is same as boolean true, in the end block, I check if `a` is true, and then print AC or NULL @user439643

Comment: @user439643 `a?"AC":"NULL"`  `a?` is a true?  yes=`"AC"` no=`"NULL"`

Comment: i want to read more about awk and sed with examples. is there any pdf or book you can suggest me?
Thanks Kent and Jotne for your help

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
if grep -q '^AC|' ABC.txt; then
  variable=AC
else
  variable=0
fi
```

Comment: i want to know by awk.. but this will also helps, thanks alot